# How can I use the "execCommand" method of an iframe in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frontend

I have an `<iframe>` named "textField" and I want to write this code in jQuery:

```
textField.document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Which command are you trying to execute?

Comment: Maybe we should focus on what you are trying to accomplish. According to MDN, you should not use execCommand. It is obsolete and may be removed at any time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand

Comment: I'm trying to create a rich text editor like shown here: VerkkoNet – YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_xN5oo_hqY